# How can i pass the value of input to the value of paypal amount in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, paypal

i'm new here and i come across a doubt on how can i pass the input value to the paypal amount, i'll leave the code below:

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from '../../Components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Video from '../../Asssets/Video/Video.mp4';
import Table from '../../Components/Table/Table';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {
  FirstPositionButton,
  ButtonBID
} from '../../Components/Buttons/Button/Button';

function RankingHome() {
  const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState('');
  const paypal = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.paypal
      .Buttons({
        createOrder: (data, actions, err) => {
          return actions.order.create({
            intent: 'CAPTURE',
            purchase_units: [
              {
                description: 'Points',
                amount: {
                  currency_code: 'EUR',
                  value: // i want to pass the input value here
                }
              }
            ]
          });
        },
        onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
          const order = await actions.order.capture();
          console.log(order);
        },
        onError: err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      })
      .render(paypal.current);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <HeroContainer>
        <HeroBg>
          <VideoBg
            src={Video}
            type="video/mp4"
            autoPlay
            loop
            muted
            playsInline
          />
        </HeroBg>
        <HeroContent>
          <HeroItems>
            <HeroH1>Who will win?</HeroH1>
            <Table />
            <div className="flexati">
              <FirstPositionButton />
              <ButtonBID text={textValue} setText={setTextValue} /> //That's my
              input value where i type my bid
              <Link to="/Pay">
                <i class="far fa-check"></i>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </HeroItems>
          <div>
            <div ref={paypal}></div>
          </div>
        </HeroContent>
      </HeroContainer>
    </>
  );
}
export default RankingHome;
```

so as u can see the input value it's the "ButtonBid" where i pass the props that i defined in the button function here:

```js
function ButtonBID(props) {
  return (
    <div class="form__group field">
      <input
        value={props.text}
        onChange={e => props.setText(e.target.value)}
        type="input"
        class="form__field"
        placeholder="Name"
        name="bid"
        id="name"
        required
      />
      <label for="name" class="form__label">
        Bid now!
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

at the end how can i pass the value of bid to the paypal amount? i tried to put {Textvalue} but nothing appeared.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is quite straightforward. According to your code, `textValue` will be changed when you type on input of `ButtonBID` component. So you can use `textValue` directly when you create order on paypal.

```js
createOrder: (data, actions, err) => {
  return actions.order.create({
      intent: "CAPTURE",
      purchase_units: [{
          description: 'Points',
          amount: {
              currency_code: "EUR",
              value: textValue // textValue is the input value
          }
      }]
  })
},
```

Comment: Yeah i've already tried but nothing , it loads in half and then the paypal page closes, likely that an integer value does not pass, if instead I try to put a fixed value I accept the payment

Comment: Try to add `textValue` to the useEffect dependency array

Comment: Ok ill try it just back at home , thank u!!

Comment: i've tried to add the `textValue` into the useEffect array but it show me the same error, i've tried to put also a console log but it show me the right value int ( for example: 555.00$) but idk why if put `textValue` it gives me error into console log instead if i use a specific value (ex: 400.00) it's a right value @baymax